# How can I remove duplicates from my file, while certain fields take priority?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

So I have SQL that will add a code to a field if it detects duplicates. There is another field called DS

DS can either be 'yes' or it can be 'no'

How can I make it so if it finds a duplicate, 'yes' is not coded and 'no' is?

Essentially 'yes' gets priority.

My SQL:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
         FROM   [PULLED REC])
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Comment: Why can't you set DS to 'no'?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Are you wanting to update all the rows for the duplicate? Do you ignore the column DS to determine if it is a duplicate? Without some details of the table and what you are trying to do this is really difficult to answer.

Comment: @SeanLange I want to update all of the rows for the duplicates, but say if we have two records

Name: Sam DS: yes
Name: Sam DS: no

Then we only code the DS = no.

Comment: I can't really help much here because there is no detail about your tables but I will through a guess in as an answer. If you want better help this would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only update rows where `ds='No'` you can add that to the `where` clause.

To make sure `rn > 1` is not skipping one of your duplicates that you need to update, you can use an `exists()` alternative to `count()`

```
with cte as (
  select   
      *
    , rn = row_number() over (
            partition by fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate
            order by (case when DS = 'yes' then 0 else 1 end) asc
            )
    from [pulled rec]
)
/* -- check with select first -- */
select * from cte

/* 
update cte set 
    bad_codes = isnull(bad_codes, '') + 'D'
--*/
/* -- Update all records that have a duplicate 
  -- except the First row, ordered by ds='Yes' first */
/*
  where cte.ds = 'No'
    and cte.rn > 1
--*/ 
-- Update all records that have a duplicate and ds='No' --
--/*
  where cte.ds = 'No'
    and exists (
      select 1
        from cte as i
        where i.rn > 1
          and i.fips_county_code = cte.fips_county_code
          and i.last = cte.last
          and i.suffix = cte.suffix
          and i.first = cte.first
          and i.birthdate = cte.birthdate
      );
--*/
```

Alternate version using `count() over()`:

```
with cte as (
  select   
      *
    , CountOver = count() over (
            partition by fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate
            )
    from [pulled rec]
)
/* -- check with select first -- */
select * from cte

/* 
update cte set 
    bad_codes = isnull(bad_codes, '') + 'D'
--*/

  where cte.ds = 'No'
    and cte.CountOver > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
                , COUNT(*) as DupeCount
         FROM   [PULLED REC]
         group by fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate --and whatever other columns are present
)
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = case RN when 1 then BAC_CODES else Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D' end
    , DS = Case DupeCount when 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end
```